# Invoke build using sshexec in remote machine does not work

Tags: ant, ssh

I have setup a SSH server in my remote machine (Windows) executing the following commands in my windows machine.

```
     <sshexec host="host"
    port="port"
    username="uname"
    password="pass"
    trust="true"
    Command="(E:; cd \buildProjectDemo\build\;  ant -propertyfile configurable.properties build-installer)"
    />
```

But, the command does not execute in the remote machine. It just gives the output as,

```
    hostExec:
  [sshexec] Connecting to host
  [sshexec] cmd : (E:; cd \buildProjectDemo\build\;  ant -propertyfile configurable.properties build-installer)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The command needs to be changed as

```
        Command="e: &amp;&amp; cd E:\buildProjectDemo\build &amp;ant -propertyfile configurable.properties build-installer"
```